# How Do I Add Methods To ActiveRecord::Base?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to create a customized ActiveRecord::Base that includes additional metadata about the connection.  I see two ways to go about this:

1.)  Inherit from ActiveRecord::Base and add methods & fields in this subclass.

2.)  Encapsulate an ActiveRecord::Base object inside my own class

1 has all kinds of problems with the inability to override initialize, weird problems where it doesn't seem to have custom methods I've added, etc.

```
undefined method `set_profile' for #<Class:0xf041f0>
```

2 I have not been able to figure out, due to problems with using ActiveRecord::Base.new

I am trying to make an all-purpose ActiveRecord class that I can dynamically establish_connection & set_table_name on, (i.e. not have one underlying table that this ActiveRecord::Base represents) but I can't seem to find a way to accomplish it.  Any ideas?

This works:

```
  class MyTable < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection $config['custom-db-config'];
    set_table_name 'MY_TABLE'
  end
```

but I need a class I can call these things on repeatedly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you'll want that, but maybe you can try this?

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    def self.your_method
      # implementation goes here
    end
  end
end
```

You will need to save this file and put it in `config/intializers`.

Comment: this worked right off the bat, thank you.  To give you a little more context, I'm writing an interface to a data warehouse, so I wanted a data source Profile class, which I could initialize with a configuration from database.yml and a table name.  This works fine (as in my original example) and I was trying to build a general class instead of having to spec out each database_config/table as a hard-coded class.  

If you have any other (better/cleaner) approaches to this situation, I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also extend the ActiveRecord::Base class in order to add the those methods dynamically which are directly callable by the class inheriting the ActiveRecord::Base...Many acts_as plugins are defined and made according to this practice...

Comment: do you have an example of how the code for this approach is a different approach than the one above?  I tried Profile < ActiveRecord::Base but seemed to just run into trouble getting it to work.

Comment: One of the things I ideally wanted to do was initialize an instance of ActiveRecord::Base by calling something like Warehouse::Profile.new (where Profile extends as in the previous comment) but I couldn't prevent it from attempting to do its magic (i.e. looking for a table called 'profiles'.)  

Curious to know what the pattern for acts_as is exactly.